# Did not receive Census badge after completing 2019 Developer Survey

Tags: support, badges, survey, survey-2019

So I filled in the "2019 Developer Survey" on the first day it was live but I did not receive the [Census badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) that should be awarded.

- Completed survey first day it went live
- logged in on Stack Overflow
- regular network/PC
- Firefox Developer Edition as browser
- Windows 10 as operating system

What should I do now?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Did you complete the survey to its very end and chose what site to get the badge on?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did complete the survey to its very end. But did not get the option to choose on what site i wanted the badge. When i visit the survey again i get the message: "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired." so it is registered that I completed the survey

Comment: hmm... sorry, only SO/SE dev can know for sure what went wrong then, and manually award you the bounty. If you don't get response here within few days, you can also click "contact us" in footer and submit a contact form.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I started a ticket at the support servers of SO/SE. I still want to thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you access your browser's history and look for such a page? https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/complete.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can. and i got redirected to a page where they asked me if i wanted the badge for SO. I assume this will work so Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Cheers, if this really works, feel free to post self answer with all the details. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard will do thanks a lot for thinking with me

Comment: `Did you complete the survey to its very end and chose what site to get the badge on?` I haven't seen anything about choosing the site the badge is awarded on. Have you done this @Shadow?

Comment: @hat no, but seen it mentioned. Guess it's only relevant when you have account on more than one "tech" site, e.g. SU, SF etc, in addition to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all huge thank you to [@shadowWizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) who helped me to a solution.

It turned out something went wrong on the final page of the survey where you can claim the badge.

**What I did to solve the problem?**

I went into my browser history `CTRL + H` and typed in `stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/complete`

Then visited the page

On the page I got the option to claim the badge after all

After a few minutes I received the badge.